# How to retrieve and display data from Firebase ONLY with JS, HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase I have the following children:

```
Temperature: 40
busvoltageOUT1: 10.192
busvoltageOUT2: 0.872
current_mAOUT1: 372.3
current_mAOUT2: -0.1
loadvoltageOUT1: 10.22893
loadvoltageOUT2: 0.87197
object: "abracadabra"
shuntvoltageOUT1: 36.93
shuntvoltageOUT2: -0.03
```

The idea is that the values ​​of these children change the integer attribute values in HTML, for this I made the following code

HTML:

```html
    <div id = "progress-circle" class = "progress-circle" data-progress = "0" data-exact = "0"> </div>
```

JS:

```js
    database.ref (). on ("value", function (snap) {
        loadvoltageOUT1 = snap.val (). loadvoltageOUT1;
        var integer = loadvoltageOUT1.toFixed ();
        var exact = loadvoltageOUT1.toFixed (2);
        var div = document.getElementById ("progress-circle");
        div.setAttribute ("data-progress", integer);
        div.setAttribute ("exact-data", exact);
        $ ('# progress-circle'). attr ('data-exact', exact);
        
        if (loadvoltageOUT1 <1) {
          $ (". VRango"). Text ("Battery Disconnected or Completely Damaged");
            }
      });
```

I wrote this Javascript code a year ago and it worked perfectly, but with the latest Javascript updates my code stopped working. However, I still can't find the error, the console doesn't show me errors either...

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your database structure looks like? You need to enter the path of resource you are looking for in `ref()`.

```
database.ref("/path/to/resource").once("value").then((snap) => {
  const data = snap.val()
  const loadvoltageOUT1 = data.loadvoltageOUT1;
  // Similarly get other fields

  const integer = loadvoltageOUT1.toFixed();
  const exact = loadvoltageOUT1.toFixed(2);


  var div = document.getElementById ("progress-circle");
  div.setAttribute("data-progress", integer);
  div.setAttribute("exact-data", exact);
  $('# progress-circle').attr('data-exact', exact);
        
  if (loadvoltageOUT1 <1) {
    $ (". VRango"). Text ("Battery Disconnected or Completely Damaged");
  }
});
```

You can similarly fetch other fields in the path specified. Make sure the ref is correct.

Answer (score 0):

for those who need it, this is how you can solve the problem (with the help of the only answer), it should be clarified that you need jquery

```
    // ------ BATTERY VOLTAGE ------
    
    // get selected information from firebase
    
   firebase.database (). ref (). on ('value', (snap) => {
   const data = snap.val ()
   const loadvoltageOUT1 = data.loadvoltageOUT1;
  
   // convert the obtained values to integral and exact numbers

   const integer = loadvoltageOUT1.toFixed ();
   const exact = loadvoltageOUT1.toFixed (2);
      
   // set the received information to the css circles

   var div = document.getElementById ("progress-circle1");
   div.setAttribute ("data-progress", integer);
   div.setAttribute ("exact-data", exact);
   $ ('# progress-circle'). attr ('data-exact', exact);
        
  
});
```